# Check if Time Value is between two values mentioned in a CSV File in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

*This question may seem difficult to understand but I'll try my best to keep it simple.* I got a CSV file with the following data:

```
Time,Meeting ID,Passcode
08:15, 953 2394 8317,091418
16:58, 953 2394 8317,091418
15:00, 807 028 8062,587838
20:02, 807 028 8062,587838
12:03, 961 8894 9557,806108
11:51, 961 8976 9546,098718
```

The first thing here is to read the CSV data and for this, I am using **pandas** imported as **pd**.

> df = pd.read_csv('meetingschedule.csv')

Also added :

> df_new = pd.DataFrame()

Now, Considering the *Time* column, the Times mentioned should be arranged/sorted in increasing order (AM to PM) and then made into a dataframe along with its rows **without writing to the CSV file**. After arranging, It may look like:

```
Time,Meeting ID,Passcode
08:15, 953 2394 8317,091418
11:51, 961 8976 9546,098718
12:03, 961 8894 9557,806108
15:00, 807 028 8062,587838
16:58, 953 2394 8317,091418
20:02, 807 028 8062,587838
```

Now, Checking the current system time, If it has crossed the 1st mentioned Time and it is before the 2nd mentioned time, then assign a variable to the dataframe for the first mentioned time's row. I have tried but could not get the **time between** stuff into my code :

```
#Check the current system time
timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

#Check if the current time is mentioned in the Dataframe
if timestr in df.Time.values:

    #Add a dataframe for that Row
    df_new = df[df['Time'].astype(str).str.contains(timestr)]
```

*Please suggest a better way* to take the two values of time into Consideration and if that time is in between both values, then make a dataframe for the row with the lower limit of time value.

*Now comes the Complex part for which I have no ideas...* I need to get this continuously iterate and check for the **"time between"** and when it crosses the Time of the Upper Limit value, the variable (Here, *df_new*) must change and store the **df** for **its row** , until it crosses the 3rd mentioned Time value and so on till it reaches the last row and for the last row, It should not worry about the next value of Time so as to avoid any "Error".

```
For an Example, Taking the Current Time to be 08:30:

    It is between the columns "08:15" and "11:51" as mentioned in the CSV, so 
    considering the Lower limit Value, It should take the row with the 
    "08:15" value and make a df with it:

    08:15, 953 2394 8317,091418

Similarly,
    
    When the time crosses 11:51, it should change the df_new value with the 
    df for the row with "11:51" value:

    11:51, 961 8976 9546,098718
```

This should also Work, If I start the Program at a time more than the Time mentioned in the first row. So, It should also search for the time value nearest but less than the value of the current time in the *Time* column.

**Thus, Its only job is to change the value in the variable (Here, *df_new*) as the time passes from one column to the next, until it reaches the bottom**.

This is because I need to write the *Meeting_ID* and the *Passcode* according to the time, everytime I rejoin the Meeting. Thus, the *df* needs to change as the time passes between the times mentioned in the CSV file. Also, I have to take this approach since I need to integrate it to my *Joining* Program so as to enter the *Id* and *Passcode* as per the schedule in the CSV.

At last, I need to keep it as a Multithreaded Operation, So *if possible*, Keep it as a threaded task so that it does not interfere with the *Main* Program (If its going to be a While Loop).

**Thanks a Lot for the Help *!!***

Comment: Your explanation is a bit complex, which is likely because you are unsure of the best approach to solve your problem. Can you _show_ what your expected output is, rather than explain? Please edit your question to include a mock up of expected output given a known time of day, and dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to take this approach only, since I have a previous program to work along with it. Hope I am more clear with the Example given. Frankly speaking, I am a beginner and your comment really helped me identify myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to solve the simpler problem of getting the current meeting time would be to:

1. convert the `Time` column to `TimeDelta`.
2. [Set the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) of the DataFrame as the new `Time` column
3. [sort by index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index)
4. Then use [get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas-index-get-loc) with the "pad" method to get the index of closest match before the given time.
5. Use that index to get the row from the DataFrame
6. Lastly Cleanup the display for output

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': {0: '08:15', 1: '16:58',
                            2: '15:00', 3: '20:02',
                            4: '12:03', 5: '11:51'},
                   'Meeting ID': {0: ' 953 2394 8317',
                                  1: ' 953 2394 8317',
                                  2: ' 807 028 8062',
                                  3: ' 807 028 8062',
                                  4: ' 961 8894 9557',
                                  5: ' 961 8976 9546'},
                   'Passcode': {0: 91418, 1: 91418,
                                2: 587838, 3: 587838,
                                4: 806108, 5: 98718}})

# Convert Times to TimeDelta
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'] + ":00")
# Set Time as Index
df = df.set_index('Time').sort_index()

# Repeatable Section
try:
    # Get Current Time
    current_dt = datetime.now()
    # For Testing (Set Time to 12:02) (Remove in Real Code)
    current_dt = current_dt.replace(hour=12, minute=2)
    # Convert Current Hour and Minute to TimeDelta
    current_delta = timedelta(hours=current_dt.hour, minutes=current_dt.minute)
    # Get the location of time before current time delta
    index_of_meeting = df.index.get_loc(current_delta, method='pad')

    # Use Location to Access Meeting Row
    meeting_row = df.iloc[[index_of_meeting]]
except KeyError:
    # Use Location Of First Meeting Of Day
    meeting_row = df.iloc[[0]]

# Cleanup Display
meeting_row = meeting_row.reset_index()
meeting_row['Time'] = meeting_row['Time'].astype(str).str[-8:]
# For Display
print(meeting_row.to_string(index=False))
```

Source (`df`):

```
 Time     Meeting ID  Passcode
08:15  953 2394 8317     91418
16:58  953 2394 8317     91418
15:00   807 028 8062    587838
20:02   807 028 8062    587838
12:03  961 8894 9557    806108
11:51  961 8976 9546     98718
```

Output:

```
    Time     Meeting ID  Passcode
11:51:00  961 8976 9546     98718
```

- Note: Current code overwrites Hours and Minutes to 12:02.

---

The line:

```py
# For Testing (Set Time to 12:02) (Remove in Real Code)
current_dt = current_dt.replace(hour=12, minute=2)
```

Was introduced for testing purposes. In a real scenario it should be removed so as to not overwrite the actual current time's hour and minute.

Comment: Thanks, That helped a Lot. This approach worked nice with the previous setup as well, And I added a loop so that it changes the **meeting_row** with time. Thanks againn !!

Comment: Heyy, One more help, As the Index is sorted out, Can you make an Edit so that in the Except Statement, Instead of printing _No Meeting at this Time_, It would take the **meeting_row** for the least value of the _Time_ column , Like in case if the current time is **08:10** and the least mentioned time in the CSV is **08:15**, then it would access that Meeting Row with **08:15**.

Comment: Updated to include this behaviour.

Comment: I'm glad that I could explain my question properly and also could a **Perfect** answer...Thanks Again !!